# Uncaught TypeError: subir_file.forEach is not a function

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with the conversion object to array..

In the next code read a file json and input de information in a div byte_content
This part of code it's ok..

```
function leer_json() {
    function readBlob(opt_startByte, opt_stopByte) {
        var files = document.getElementById('files').files;
        if (!files.length) {
            alert('Please select a file!');
            return;
        }

        var file = files[0];
        var start = parseInt(opt_startByte) || 0;
        var stop = parseInt(opt_stopByte) || file.size - 1;
        var reader = new FileReader();

        // If we use onloadend, we need to check the readyState.
        reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
            if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) { // DONE == 2
                document.getElementById('byte_content').textContent = evt.target.result;
                subir_file = evt.target.result;
                alert(subir_file);
            }
        };
        var blob = file.slice(start, stop + 1);
        reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
    }

    document.querySelector('.readBytesButtons').addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
        if (evt.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'button') {
            var startByte = evt.target.getAttribute('data-startbyte');
            var endByte = evt.target.getAttribute('data-endbyte');
            readBlob(startByte, endByte);
        }
    }, false);
}
```

The second function capture the var subir_file and try the read with the 
each but the problem its of diferent type the date..

```
function sube_json() {

    var table = document.getElementById('d_t_json');
    subir_file.forEach(function(object) {
        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
        tr.innerHTML = '<td>' + object.Tipo + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + object.Idenfificacion + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + object.Periodo_inicial + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + object.Periodo_final + '</td>';
        table.appendChild(tr);
    });
}
```

please .. how I can change the code .. I need charge the json into talbe of  html  ..

Comment: I don't understand where your issue is. The *sube_json()* function it's not going to work until the *readBlob()* is executed, as far as I could understand your code is a global variable and is assigned inside a trigger event function... long story... the short is it will never works as the function that assign a value to that variable is addes as listener to the onload event, but this is done on an event handler onclik that means the onload is alredy run. You should redesign your code, and please avoid the globals, you can call the function and pass the value.

Comment: it's that correct , the method that activate is :

 <button  class="btn btn-warning"  onClick="javascript: leer_json()" ,  javascript: sube_json()" >Mostrar</button>

I will correc the function for acept pass the value. ..

but the main problem , is in this point 

 subir_file.forEach(function(object) {
  
subir_file is mistake to work with the funcion(object)..

I would like make the convertion the object subir_file to array [ ]..

I don't know make this...

Comment: You have to check the request result to know how the data are structured. But again don't use a global variable like *subir_file*, just pass the proper data on *sube_json()* function as a parameter, you could continue to call it in the same way, just avoid globals.

Comment: ok I made the change..
I include in the first function

[
--fist function
subir_file = evt.target.result;                 
sube_json(subir_file);

--second function
  function sube_json(dato)
       {   
          
        alert(dato);
        var table = document.getElementById('d_t_json');
        dato.forEach(function(object) {

In this line mark the mistake...
Descarga_json.js:224 Uncaught TypeError: dato.forEach is not a function(…) 
]

Comment: You shoud check if *dato* is an array. Use *console.dir(dato)* to print it on console.